# Exporting map from TileMill to PDF/SVG

Tags: pdf, mapbox, adobe-illustrator, tilemill

I have such a big problem with exporting and importing map from TileMill to Illustrator/Inkscape. The problem is with strokes of labels / names.

It seems that TileMill export each letter of label as a separate expanded path–object and doing an outline of that. The result is very bad. Take a look: http://cl.ly/image/0Z2o2v3v2r2C

Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Or maybe there is a solution to create a working text path in Illustrator from that kind of object?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using graphics software. Ask on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately an [upstream bug in Mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/535), and upstream from there in the raw SVG rendering libraries it uses.